# A proper way to debug HTTP POST in Alamofire 4; HTTP POST not working

Tags: swift, http, post, request, alamofire

I have a simple piece of code that used to work below.

```
let params: Parameters! = ["xmldata": self.makeXML(), "reference": self.questionnaire!.jobRef!]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
                .validate()
                .responseString { response in
                    print("Success: \(response.result)")
                    print("Response: \(response.response)")
                    print("Request: \(response.request)")
                    print("Error: \(response.error)")
                   // print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
                }
```

The code suppose to request http post to a simple web form below.

```
<form action="/submit?textarea=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p>Paste XML data here.</p>

      <input id="id_reference" maxlength="50" name="reference" type="text" placeholder="Reference.." /><br>
      <textarea id="id_xmldata" maxlength="5000" name="xmldata" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

      <br>
      <input type="submit" 
             name="textarea_post_form" 
             value="Send" />
      </form>
```

The code should just post 2 strings as parameters to the form on the website and insert data to the database. It used to work with Alamofire 3 and Swift 2, but not is not working with AlamoFire 4 and Swift 3 anymore. Now I have no idea why it is not working, and have no clue where I should begin to debug since I can't find a way to see if the proper data is sent or if there's some error at the server side.

Is there a way to fix this or perhaps trace the error?

What I got from the print statement doesn't seem to have any error...

```
Success: SUCCESS
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 508807148.851, "Initial Response Time": 508807148.948, "Request Completed Time": 508807148.949, "Serialization Completed Time": 508807148.950, "Latency": 0.098 secs, "Request Duration": 0.099 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.099 secs }
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000225520> { URL: http://philips-survey.in.th/submit?textarea=1 } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 14 Feb 2017 23:18:59 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Cookie,Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} })
Request: Optional(http://xxxx.com/submit?textarea=1)
Error: nil
```

Comment: The response has a 200 status code, it should work. There's any chance the error is in the server side?

Comment: Try to change `validate()` to `validate(statusCode: 200..<600)` Why? I don't know, it worked for me.

Comment: @JuanCurti Response should be 302. Once the form is submitted, the page should redirect to another page...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using uploading multipartFormData with Alamofire? Something like this:
`Network.CustomManager.upload(.POST, postEndpoint, headers: headers,     multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in ...`